# How to upgrade to Windows 10 using ISO (not using Windows Update)?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have a Windows 7 (64 bit) notebook, and I want to use the free upgrade to Windows 10.

I want to do a fresh install, not using the update mechanism. I have proper backups of all useful data from the notebook.

While installing and activating Windows 10, will my Windows 7 key (printed on the sticker at the notebook bottom side) be valid? (Or do I have to "register" it for the upgrade first, by running the Windows 10 update via Windows Update, which is what I do **not** want.)

What would be the right ISO image to use?

Comment: You start the upgrade from within Windows, when asked what you want to keep, choose "Nothing" this results in the type of installation you want.  The only way to result in an activated copy of Windows 10 is to perform the upgrade from your eligible installation of Windows.  "While installing and activating Windows 10, will my Windows 7 key (printed on the sticker at the notebook bottom side) be valid?" - Not as of today.

Answer (score 1):

not-a-user,

You will need to do the Windows Update Windows 10 Installation first in order to convert your key from Windows 7 to 10. Once the upgrade has completed, make sure you've been activated by Microsoft. Open up the new Settings app, then head to Update & Security, Activation. It will say on the right whether you're activated or not. Also note down what version of Windows 10 you have (Home, Pro). Once done proceed to the next part.

Please take a look at the below image, this should tell you what version of the Windows 10 ISO to choose which you can find by going to this [Microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10). Download the tool and go from there to create a boot-able USB/DVD.

[image: Windows 10 Edition's]

Once the above has been completed [follow this guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install?ocid=ms_wol_win10) and look towards the bottom of the page you will see the clean installation part which will take you through the steps.

Comment: A Windows 7 key isn't converted to a Windows 10 key.  You also don't have to perform the upgrade through Windows Update, you just have to perform the upgrade, and you can do that by downloading and running the installation from the .ISO.

Comment: You do have to perform the upgrade once, after that you can wipe and install.

Comment: @Ramhound: You mean I have to boot the iso but select something like "upgrade my existing Windows 7"?

Comment: There are about 5 questions that describe the process of upgrading an eligible installation of Windows to Windows 10 on this site you should read them all.  There is no reason to "wipe and install" the "keep nothing" option does EXACTLY that.